# Interpretation of the ratio of two pdfs evaluated at a certain point?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, likelihood-ratio, differential-privacy

What is the interpretation of the ratio of two pdfs evaluated at a certain point?

Is that a statistical distance?

Is there any applications of it?

I only know one application of differential privacy, i.e., laplace mechanism.

$$
\frac{f_{D}(z)}{f_{D'}(z)} \leq exp({\epsilon})
$$

This says that given a two database $D, D'$ which differ at most one record, we can bound the ratio of pdfs each representing a probability distribution of the output of a certain query processing on a database  with a randomness (i.e., each database gives a different probability distribution), as a privacy leakage with parameter $\epsilon$.

In general, what's the meaning of the ratio of two pdfs?

Comment: The likelihood ratio is central to testing and model comparison.

Comment: The ratio, under very general assumptions, is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of one measure with respect to the other.